# Perl Substring extraction using regex: Split vs Substitution

Tags: performance, perl, substring

I have written the following snippets of code to split a properties string:

### Input

```
$line='VarBinds=var0\=DU_/data02;var1\=GE;var2\=95;var3\=LT;var4\=95;var5\=95';
```

### Code 1:

```
my ($field,@v)=split /=/, $line;
my $value=join '=', @v;
```

### Code 2:

```
my $field=$line;
my $value = $field;
$field =~ s#^([[:alnum:]]+)=.*#$1#;
$value =~ s#^[[:alnum:]]+=##;
```

Which is a better piece of code, and why? [This article](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=591988) on `perl monks` leads me to believe that `Code 1` is better than `Code 2`, but I am not sure.

Please note that I've used the code below(which is better than both `Code 1` and `Code 2`).

### My Code:

```
my ($field,$value)=split /=/, $line, 2;
```

Any improvement to `My Code` are also welcome.

### EDIT:

- Clarified the question a bit.

Comment: your last example is good if it does what you want.

Comment: code 2 improvement: `my ($field,$value) = $line =~ /^([^=]+)=(.*)/;`. But the last one is faster maybe

Comment: What is your definition of "better"? If it is performance then have a look at (eg) https://metacpan.org/module/Benchmark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a limit on `split` is good, if you can rely on the order of your fields. Code #2 is somewhat crude, but does the same basic job (assuming that no string contains newlines). Your method, and code #1 and #2 all ignore the escaped equal signs, though. You can use [`Text::ParseWords`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aParseWords) to overcome that:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Text::ParseWords;

my $line = 'VarBinds=var0\=DU_/data02;var1\=GE;var2\=95;var3\=LT;var4\=95;';
my @f = quotewords('=', 1, $line);
print Dumper \@f;
```

**Output**

```
$VAR1 = [
          'VarBinds',
          'var0\\=DU_/data02;var1\\=GE;var2\\=95;var3\\=LT;var4\\=95;'
        ];
```

Comment: Not exactly what I expected, but accepting it as it taught me something new.